# time series behaved weirdly with plot_ly

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, plotly

Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

test <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~Date, ~Score, ~comp,
  "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 5, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 3, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 4, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 5, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-3-2020" , 5, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-3-2020" , 2, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-4-2020" , 5, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-5-2020" , 5, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-6-2020" , 4, "PC1",
    "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 5, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 3, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 4, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-2-2020" , 5, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-3-2020" , 5, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-3-2020" , 2, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-4-2020" , 5, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-5-2020" , 5, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "3-6-2020" , 4, "PC2",
    "Ken" , "7-6-2020", 4, "PC3"
) %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date))
```

I would like to transform this to a faceted time series plot, like this:

```
plot <- test %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Date, y=Score)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  ylim(1,5.3) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ comp)

plot
```

[image]

But when I use plotly, it looks like this.

```
ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

What is the problem? The x-axis looks weird

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just needed to add scale_x_date(), like this:

```
ggplotly(plot + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%Y"))
```

[image]